# Find the equation of the image of the line $x+y=1$ by Möbius transformation

Tags: mobius-transformation

Find the equation of the image of the line $x+y=1$ by Möbius transformation $$w=\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}$$

My approach, if $x=\Re(z)$ , and $y=\Im(z)$, then $x+y=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2})z+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2})\overline{z}-1=0$, then if $$w=\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}\implies z=\dfrac{w+1}{w-1}$$ And then we have a equation for a line, this is correct?

Comment: $x+y=1$ in the sense that $z=x+iy$?

Comment: I assumed that, the exercise only says that x +y=1

Answer (score 1):

The line $L: x+y=1$ corresponds to $z = x+(1-x)i$.

A Mobius transform $m$ maps generalizd circles onto generalized circles. 
Note, a generalized circle in the complex plane is either a circle or a straight line (a circle passing through $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere).

We need three points on $L$ and their images under $m$.
$$z_1 = 1,z_2= i, z_3 = \infty$$

$$m(z_1) = \infty,\, m(z_2) = \dfrac{i+1}{i-1}=-i,\,m(z_3) = 1$$

S0, 
$$m(L): w = x + (x-1)i \mbox{ or } y-x=-1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x+y=1$ if and only if $z=x+i(1-x)$, so in fact we have that

\begin{align*}\frac{x+i(1-x)+1}{x+i(1-x)-1}&=\frac{[x+1+i(1-x)]\cdot[(x-1)+i(x-1)]}{(x-1)^2+(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{x^2-1+i(x^2-1)-i(1-x)^2+(1-x)^2}{2(x-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{x^2-1+(1-x)^2}{2(x-1)^2}+\frac{i(x^2-1)-i(1-x)^2}{2(x-1)^2}\end{align*}

and note that this is on the line $y=x$.

Now suppose that

we have some $a+ai \in \mathbb C$. Then you need to find some $x+i(1-x)$ so that the mobius function applied to it lands you at $a+ai$ to see that the line surjects onto the line $y=x$. I plugged it in symbollically [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/a%2Bai%3D%5Cleft(x%2Bi%5Cleft(1%E2%88%92x%5Cright)%2B1%5Cright)%2F%5Cleft(x%2Bi%5Cleft(1%E2%88%92x%5Cright)%E2%88%921%5Cright)), but it seems quite complicated. On the other hand, it is continuous so it sends connected components to connected components, and it is not bounded since it is a nontrivial map, so surjectivity follows from the theory.